# How to compile for Android 4.4 using latest version of Xamarin forms in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 (Version 15.4.1) with Xamarin 4.7.10.22 and the Android SDK for 4.4.2 (API 19)  installed

I create a new Cross Platform App (Xamarin) and select

UI Technology -> Xamarin.Forms

Code Sharing Strategy -> Shared Project

I compile and build this project and it builds correctly.  (By default the project is using the latest platform (in my case 8.0 Oreo))

In Visual Studio 2017 UI has changed slightly and now when I right click Android project and choose properties -> Application -> I have only this option to select.

["Compile using Android Version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtF9G.png)

So I select Android 4.4 (Kit Kat) and build the project.

I get the following error message

`Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:elevation'`

This is good, elevation was introduced in Android 5 so I need to rebuild using  Xamarin forms for 4.4 (I think)

and this is where I get stuck, how do I tell Visual Studio I want to create a project for 4.4 not 8.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms supports API 15+, I think you are confusing the compile Xamarin.Android Framework version, the Android Framework version and min. version

> Additionally, the target/compile version for Android projects **must be set to Use latest installed platform**. However the minimum version can be set to API 15 so you can continue to support devices that use Android 4.0.3 and newer. These values are set in the Project Options

Re: [Xamarin.Forms Getting Started](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/)

Re: [Understanding Android API Levels](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework)

Comment: You are correct I have got the three fields confused, One last quick question now I have it set up correctly. "Would calling a function that is not available on my 'Target Android Version' display a warning message at compile time"?  The documentation is not completely clear on this.

Comment: @ChrisB Newer methods are flagged with method attributes (i.e. `ApiSince = 23`), you will see these in the IDE as hints, but they would not cause compiler warning/errors. You would need to perform runtime checks to skip or run alternative code : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#Runtime_Checks_for_Android_Versions Device/Emulator testing is needed on the various APIs that you are supporting with your app

Comment: Great, I'll do some research on the testing side which should fit in quite nicely to this,  Many thanks for your assistance